# Accessing methods in other models ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss

Having some trouble getting my head around accessing a method from another model. Can't seem to fix my code.

My ruby on rails application is a simple RSS reader. I have two models, Feeds and FeedEntries, I'm trying to loop though the urls in Feeds and pass them onto a method in FeedEntries which will phrase them and add them to the database. The latter is working find but having trouble accessing the update_from_feed method from my Feeds model here are my model's code:

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    feed.entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :name         => entry.title,
          :summary      => entry.summary,
          :url          => entry.url,
          :published_at => entry.published,
          :guid         => entry.id
          )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my feeds model:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch_all
    feeds.each do |feed|
      FeedEntry.update_from_feed(feed.url)
    end
  end
end
```

When I jump into the console to try and run Feed.fetch_all I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `feeds'
```

I bet this is a really silly error, But I can't get my head around how to fix it? Thanks for reading.

Comment: `feeds` is an undefined variable. If you want to reference the dataset for the `Feed` model, use `Feed`. So, for example, `Feed.all.each ...`

Comment: @mbratch thanks for the reply! I've changed feeds.each to Feed.all.each I now get "NameError: uninitialized constant Feed::Feeds" sorry hope I've understood you're response correctly.

Comment: Can you show your corrected code? You must be using `Feeds` instead of `Feed`.

Comment: My own fault I didn't reload the console which was in sandbox mode, your first response fixed my issue! Thank you so much! Would you like to answer and I'll accept?

Comment: Question relates to mis-reading of the error message about the variable, so can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed! Feeds model should have looked like this:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch_all
    Feed.all.each do |feed|
      FeedEntry.update_from_feed(feed.url)
    end
  end
end
```